# Nestjs module takes too much time to Load

Tags: typescript, module, graphql, nestjs, nodemon

Nestjs hot reloading takes too much time.
On addition of logs I found that it's due to a particular module and the picture of folder structure and the loading time is attached.

Nothing is out of the ordinary in this module compared to the rest of the modules and most of the other modules are much much complex and bigger than this one (w.r.t code, dependencies and packages used) and this module is not using any thing/component/package that other modules are not using.

So, Any particular way I can debug this?
[Module loading times Nestjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDM5w.png)

[(the one causing problem) ImageMedia Module structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv751.png)

Comment: What are you importing into `ImageMediaModule`? It could be that it's dependencies are taking a long time to load

Comment: It's impossible to help diagnose this without more information. You'll need to share at least the definition for `ImageMediaModule` and if that doesn't work you'll need a minimal reproduction that shows this problem in isolation